# Good Resources to learn ExtJs 4?

Tags: extjs

I`m searching for complete tutorial to build a crud example using ExtJs 4 with PHP,

So ... Can you help me to find a good resources in English to learn it,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192519-ExtJS-4-MVC-Application-Architecture-%28Simple-CRUD-Application-Account-Manager%29) for an example using Ext JS 4x, and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuotOCjbksY)

The main CRUD configuration you'll experience is likely on Ext JS's proxy object, the API of which allows tailoring of the various actions. See [here in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-api)